# Dropping voltage

Tags: voltage

I have some LDO regulators but I cannot dissipate enough heat.

Is it possible to reduce voltage on each branch before going through the regulator ? I was thinking about some resistors.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Then use a heatsink dude.

Comment: I've got a size restriction I cannot put one

Comment: Buck converters rely on low-impedance input supply. If you passively reduce voltage with resistors, you will need to put bypass caps on each converter (unless they are already there). Is this 5V@1A? The picture is really obscure.

Comment: My Dc power supply is 12v 5A and each branches is usung 5V 0.7A, I can dissipate heat around 6.5V 0.7A

Comment: I am using LM2940 converter with 0.5 uf capacitor before and 470 uf after

Comment: A good 3.5W buck converter should dissipate no more than 500-700mW. You say you can tolerate 4.55W. How it is that your system can't handle this dissipation?

Comment: Since I cannot use heatsink, from the datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2940-n.pdf) junction-to-ambiant which I'm assuming is the indication for system without heatsink just ambiant air is 23.3°C/W and max is 125°C

Comment: You are using LDO regulator, not "buck converter". LDO will dissipate a lot in this situation. You should use real "buck" switching regulator if power dissipation is of concern.

Comment: I cannot use big components

Comment: 470uF cap alone is big. Did you consider something like "DC-DC Module", http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/recom-power/R-78E5.0-1.0/945-2201-ND/4930585

Comment: I am actually using a [small capacitor](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-sprague/293D477X96R3D2TE3/718-1749-1-ND/2259973) It looks a little big and a bit expensive

Comment: A 6.3V tant on a 5V rail is really pushing it, usual rule of thumb if you must do the tant thing is to derate by 50% or so. Tantalum caps have a nasty failure mode if care is not taken, and while they have their place, it is not generic supply decoupling these days.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a linear regulator, not a buck converter (as @AliChen pointed out), the total power you dissipate will be (Vout - Vin) * current. Adding resistors won't change this equation; it will just move heat from the regulator chip to the resistor.

If you want to avoid the heat dissipation, you should use a buck converter. (The first line of your question says you're using a buck converter, but in the comments you say it's a LM2940 regulator, not a buck converter.)

To put some numbers on this, you say you have 5 branches, each with 5V at .7A. So linear regulation will dissipate 7V * 3.5A = 24.5 watts. If you use a 90% efficient buck converter, you will dissipate 10% * 5V * 3.5A which is just 1.75 watts.

Alternatively, can you use a 9V (or lower) power supply? This would cut the dissipation down to 14 watts.

Comment: I cannot change the power supply, I'm avoiding dissipation because of space, un buck converter is a little bulkier

Comment: @user126774, then you're constrained by physics, as Ken Shirriff and others have stated. The linear solutions you favour will dissipate a total number of Watts, be they in one regulator or shared across resistors and regulators. A switch-mode regulator will dissipate much less heat. I'm afraid there is no third option beyond reduce the load or the input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I am reasonably confident that a modern 3.5A internal power switch buck running at 1MHz or so will be of the same order of size as your 5 linear regs + 5 tants (Especially once you beef the voltage rating on those 6.3V tants up to something that might actually make them reliable!), and will be FAR more efficient .

LM8610AC looks sane at first glance, datasheet has a 2MHz design with a 2.2uH inductor and all ceramic caps which looks reasonable to me. Layout matters with that stuff, so follow the datasheet design.